# unable to get the value in the constructor in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here my issue is when i am  clicking on the button i am setting a value in button click method  and in the contructor i am declaring that variable but i unable to get that value below is my code and i am getting undefined in constructor

```
     public dat = {
  "pexels-photo.jpeg": {
    "information": "laptop",
    "desc": {
      "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
      "id": "shsj44",
      "file_id": "pexels-photo.jpeg"
    },
    "_id": "shsj44"
  }
};
  fileid= "";
  constructor(){
    console.log(this.fileid);

    // HERE A URL HAS TO BE CALLED WITH PARAM AS FILEID;
  }

  getData(){
   Object.keys(this.dat).forEach(key => {
      var value = this.dat[key];
      // console.log(key +':',value["_id"]);
      this.fileid = value["_id"];
      console.log(this.fileid);

    });
  }
```

below is my stackblitz :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dr7ehj

i am declaring that variable in constructor bcoz i need to call some info using this value in contructor

Comment: What do you mean by: in the contructor i am declaring that variable but i unable to get that value? You are unable to get that value where? In the getData function?

Comment: when i click on the get data method i am setting a value and in next step i want that value from constructor

Comment: Just a comment, you shouldn't do no functions in constructor. Angular has `OnInit` for handling such things ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have not declare variable in constructor, you just log the value of variable in constructor.

you will get undefined in constructor as you are not assigning value please see below code

```
fileid='information';
  constructor(){
    console.log(this.fileid);
  }

  getData(){
    this.fileid = "infomation Updated";
    console.log(this.fileid);
  }
```

it will log updated info while clicking on button.

Comment: here i click on  getData() then information updated info has to get in the constructer as well

Comment: please call getData() in constructor before you use fileid, it should work.

Comment: please find updated stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dr7ehj

Answer (score 0):

It is working correctly. The value that is being console.log is undefined because you have not given it a value so it has been declared but not defined;

you could give it an initial value either where you are declaring it or inside of the constructor itself;

If you just want it to equal 'information' on click then you want to move your console.log to the getData() method and it will log the updated fileId on click of the button.

Remember the constructor will only be called once so if you want to log after the button is pressed you need to move this to the getData method. if you have any services or anything else you can pass them in as private parameters to the constructor and you can access them later on in the getData method or any other method you have.

```
constructor(private service: MyService) {} // dont need to do anything in constructor

getData() {
    this.fileId = 'information'
    console.log(this.fileId);
    this.service(this.fileId); // or some other custom code here
}
```

You can also utilize [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) to fire something everytime a specific value changes

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // use url with fileId as param here
}
```

The problem with calling a url in the constructor is initially the param is undefined so you would be sending an invalid url initially.

Comment: have you tried on button click and able to get the value ? & i dont want to give the value in the constructor and in a method i am giving it

Comment: yes that will set the value to information. If you put the console.log inside of getData(). it will log information

Comment: see i need that variable in constructor only thats what i am trying

Comment: what do you need it in the constructor for?

Comment: please check the updated code in stackblitz and i need bcoz when i click on the  button click the " id" will be sent to the variable and in the constructor a url will be called for that parameter is this id and that url only be called in constructor thats why

Comment: Answer has been updated. since it is only being called when the button is clicked I would call the url somewhere other than the constructor. The constructor should be used only for initial state of your component. The id doesn't exist until the button click so I think it would be best to move this code for the url to the getData method. Alternatively you could move it to ngOnChanges which gets called when things change.